# API Dictionary French with illustration by image

Tags: api, dictionary, french

I want to a API dictionnary for French that explains a given word by image.
It can be free or with fee, XML or JSON, REST or SOAP,...

All I want is a API or a solution/ library that I call it with a word, and it returns an image.
I spent a lot of time to search in the Internet but not found

For example, I want to find a word

**Compter** *(Count in English)*, it returns an image in which a person is counting the money in a table.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What kind of API are you looking for? A web (REST) API? Or some library? Where do you want to address it from?

Comment: Try searching on google you will get many, ami. Else try this: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/api/collins-french-dictionary-benedict,65,HCA.html Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: What license do you need the images to be? How realistic do you want the images to be? Do they need to be photos or are sketches enough? One image may not be enough. Some words have double meaning. The API might also return nothing, e.g. for abstract words like "piece" and words that are not nouns. IMHO such an API will be of little help, which might be a reason why nobody has developed it yet.